# How to install rl_json on tcl8.5 in windows?

Tags: json, tcl

I was trying to install `rl_json` using

```
teacup install rl_json
```

But this installer is not present in `teacup`.

Please suggest to install it.

Comment: This isn't the right place for this request. See https://wiki.tcl.tk/17305

Comment: Unfortunately, ActiveState have not been very good at supporting their package repository recently (for business reasons).

Comment: Donal, I have analysed the `huddle` and `json::write` modules for tcl to json conversion. I want to look into the features of `rl_json` for our requirements. Any trial version of  `rl_json` is available ..